# Android: Canvas from scratch

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am experimenting with building a custom game engine based on standard Canvas drawing that resembles the Android View class in that drawable objects have an onDraw method. The idea is that the game elements are given a Canvas on which to draw themselves and that is then incorporated into the main view. I assume that there is something similar going on behind the scenes with the standard Android Views.

How can I create a "master view" that can hand small Canvases to child objects and then incorporate those canvases into it's own drawing?

NOTE: the child objects are not subclasses of View, but the "master" view can be a View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the [Android Source Code](http://source.android.com) for `View` and `ViewGroup` I discovered how this is done. When the system draws views to the screen, it generates a Canvas which is a rastor for the entire screen. That Canvas is not "cut up" and given to subviews to draw on, but rather it is translated and clipped to accomodate each view.

Before a particular view is drawn, its parent translates the Canvas to the child's position, clips the Canvas to the child's size, and then calls `.draw(Canvas)` on that view. The view does not know that the canvas has been altered, each view draws as if it were at (0,0). After the child has finished drawing, the Canvas is translated back to its previous position. Abstractly, every view thinks it is the only view, when in reality each parent is repositioning and resizing the canvas to be in the right place.

So for my situation, all I needed to do was iterate each of my child objects like this:

```
for(MyObject mob : mobjects) {
   final int restoreTo = canvas.save();

   canvas.translate(mob.getX(), mob.getY());
   canvas.clipRect(0, 0, mob.getWidth(), mob.getHeight());
   mob.onDraw(canvas);

   canvas.restoreToCount(restoreTo);
}
```